# В какое время сбрасывать однодневный таймаут?

Tags: разработка-игр, дизайн, ux

Есть ивенты в игре, которые должны быть доступны раз в день. Вопрос в том, когда сбрасывать этот таймаут: в одно и то же время ночью (скажем, в 00:00) или именно в то время, когда пользователь закончил выполнение предыдущего ивента? В первом случае проблема в том, что можно 2 раза подряд выполнить ивент, что противоречит идее "раз в день", во втором - если пользователь зашёл в игру на час раньше, то вынужден ждать, хотя уже наступил новый день, что раздражает, а если на час позже, то и в следующий день обязан тоже на час позже делать.

Есть какие-нибудь статьи на эту тему в гейм-дизайне?

Comment: Делайте как вам угодно. Я видел реализацию и первого и второго случая. В чем собственно у вас вопрос?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev вопрос - как лучше делать? Конкретно можно перечислить плюсы и минусы указанных подходов, предоставить третий вариант, если есть, дать ссылки на статьи/литературу по теме.

Comment: А почему это в первом случае можно выполнить ивент два раза? После прохождения ивента в БД ставится галочка об этом, а в полночь сбрасывается.. Соответственно если галочка есть, то ивент не давать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский имеется в виду, что прошёл в 23:55 и сразу же в 00:00 можешь снова проходить, т.е. в одной игровой сессии очень близко

Comment: И что? Вам какая разница?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, если, например, ивент это квест, как-то логически связанный со сменой дня и ночи (т.к. раз в день), то это вредит "реалистичности" игры

Comment: Вы, голубчик, для начала определитесь в типах своих ивентов, а потом выстраиайте логику. Если это независимый ивент суточный - то без разницы когда сбрасывать, главное раз в сутки, если что-то там с днём и ночью зависит (хотя я так и не понял что и как), то, надо смотреть на доп. условия... А под одну гребëнку в таком случае всё не грести.

Comment: Вот я сейчас играю в известную игру forge of empires. Там всё сбрасывается в определённое время. Есть так называемые поля битв, где люди воюют и при этом там набираются так называемые штрафы-каждый бой всё сложнее вести. А каждую полночь штрафы сбрасываются. В этом часто стратегия и заключается - до полуночи начать бить, чтобы сразу после полуночи ещё дозахватывать.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вот, это же пример, почему это плохо, т.к. игра позволяет абузить таким образом игровые механики! Плюс разным людям делать это сложнее из-за часовых поясов, у некоторых в "серверную полночь" 3 ночи, а у некоторых 10 вечера.

Comment: А вот и нет, для стратегической игры это важно, т.к надо рассчитывать свои силы и подумать стратегию, чтобы правильно захватить сектора. Т.е. нужно не просто кнопки тыкать, но ещё и думать головой...... А в целом, вам-то какая разница? У вам смысл дать ивент пользователю раз в сутки, почему вас должно волновать что он это сделал близко по интервалу. Это всё равно что прийти в Пятёрочку перед закрытием, потом прямо в открытие с утра а вас не пустят за хлебом, т.к. уже были 8 часов назад... Бред... Если это критичная ситуация - ок, а когда надо дать просто ивент - зачем такие загоны - не ясно

Comment: У кого-то ночь, у кого-то не ночь, - ещё раз, Вы определитесь что у вас, а то вы условия на ходу добавляете, прям как заказчик  напомню, что можно делать игру и локально зависимой 

Comment: По поводу ивента. В БД в таблице событий можно держать время доступности события, например 14:00. Галочки можно сбрасывать например в полночь, а доступен ивент будет если галочка о прохождении отсутствует И если по времени тоже доступно